# jQuery combine on('click') and if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am developing side navigation that I will be able to re-use and I want to implement some data attributes. Is it possible to combine on('click') event and if statement in the way that I need to jQuery trigger function on click or if `data-open="true"` so side navigation is open by default. The point is that I don't want to rewrite all the code for open attribute. Maybe something that will trigger onClick one time before page is loaded if `data-open="true"`. Sorry for bad English

this is my HTML:

```
<nav class="side-nav side-nav-right" data-push="true" data-open="true" data-opacity="true">
    <div class="side-toggle-button">
        <div class="icon-bar"></div>
        <div class="icon-bar"></div>
        <div class="icon-bar"></div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

and this is JavaScript

```
// Side Navigation
$('.side-toggle-button').on('click', function() {
    var push = $('.side-nav').data().push;
    var opacity = $('.side-nav').data().opacity;
    var open= $('.side-nav').data().open;

    $('.side-nav').toggleClass('side-nav-open');

    // Left Side Navigation
    if ($('.side-nav').hasClass('side-nav-left')){
        $(this).toggleClass('side-toggle-button-left');

        //Left Side Push Option
        if (push === true) {
            $('body').toggleClass('side-nav-push-right');
        }

    // Right Side Navigation
    } else {
        $(this).toggleClass('side-toggle-button-right');

        //Right Side Push Option
        if (push === true) {
            $('body').toggleClass('side-nav-push-left');
        }
    }

    // Opacity Option
    if (opacity === true) {
        $('body').toggleClass('side-nav-opacity');
    }

});
// Side Navigation End
```

Here is CodePen:
https://codepen.io/Klak031/pen/EXwdRw

Comment: Well, yes, it's possible to use an `if` statement in JavaScript.  What specifically in your code isn't working as expected?  When you debug, what are the values of your variables?

Comment: just make it into a function that runs on document.ready

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put your code into a function, use the function as the callback for the event listener and call the function on load:

```
// Event listener
$('.side-toggle-button').on('click', slideToggleNav);

// Function itself
function slideToggleNav() {
    var push = $('.side-nav').data().push;
    var opacity = $('.side-nav').data().opacity;
    var open= $('.side-nav').data().open;

    $('.side-nav').toggleClass('side-nav-open');

    // Left Side Navigation
    if ($('.side-nav').hasClass('side-nav-left')){
        $(this).toggleClass('side-toggle-button-left');

        //Left Side Push Option
        if (push === true) {
            $('body').toggleClass('side-nav-push-right');
        }

    // Right Side Navigation
    } else {
        $(this).toggleClass('side-toggle-button-right');

        //Right Side Push Option
        if (push === true) {
            $('body').toggleClass('side-nav-push-left');
        }
    }

    // Opacity Option
    if (opacity === true) {
        $('body').toggleClass('side-nav-opacity');
    }
}

// Call to function
slideToggleNav();
```